# Base64 InputStream to String

Tags: java, base64

I have been trying to get an input stream reading a file, which isa plain text and has embeded some images and another files in `base64` and write it again in a String. But keeping the encoding, I mean, I want to have in the String something like:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIf
IiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7Pj4+JS5ESUM8SDc9Pjv/2wBDAQoLCw4NDhwQEBw7KCIoOzs7Ozs7
```

I have been trying with the classes `Base64InputStream` and more from packages as `org.apache.commons.codec` but I just can not fiugure it out. Any kind of help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Piece of code using a reader:

```
 BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bodyPart.getInputStream()));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                        }
                        br.close();
```

Getting as a result something like: `.DIC;ÿÛC;("(;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;ÿÀ@@"ÿÄ`

Comment: I don't get it. Why don't you simply use a simple reader if you don't want to decode it ?

Comment: Because the base64 encoding is not suported

Comment: You use base64 to encode bytes in a limited set of characters that are unchanged with almost all char encodings, for example ASCII or UTF-8. Base64 isn't a charset encoding.

Comment: I have just edited my question, with a piece of code using a bufferreader. It is not what I need, I get something like:  .DIC;ÿÛC;("(;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;ÿÀ@@"ÿÄ

Comment: What's the encoding of the file ? "plain text" isn't precise enough.

Comment: ANSI. It is an .eml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, inspired by this post [getting base64 content string of an image from a mimepart in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764504/getting-base64-content-string-of-an-image-from-a-mimepart-in-java)

I think it is kind of stupid decode and encode again the base64 code, but it is the only way I found to manage this issue. If someone could give a better solution, it would be also really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing this:

`final byte[] bytes64bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
 final String content = new String(bytes64bytes);`

Answer (score 1):

A text file containing some base64 data can be read with the charset of the rest of the file.

[Base64 encoding](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a mean to encode bytes in a limited set of characters that are unchanged with almost all char encodings, for example ASCII or UTF-8.

Base64 isn't a charset encoding, you don't have to specify you have some base64 encoded data when reading a file into a string.

So if your text file is generally UTF-8 (that's probable), you can read it without problem even if it contains a base64 encoded stream. Simply use a basic reader and don't use a Base64InputStream if you don't want to decode it.

When opening a file with a reader, you have to [specify the encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29). If you don't know it, I suggest you test with the probable ones, like `UTF-8`, `US-ASCII` or `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Bit the problem is not fixed. The problem is that I don´t open any file. I am working with MimeMessage and Multipart, giving only the path. How could I specify then the encoding?

Comment: You didn't say before it was eml... You don't have to provide the charset as RFC 822 precise it must contain only US-ASCII. I think that MimeMessage handles the charset on a simple InputStream.

Comment: Apparently is not a simple InputStream, I can not just read it and copy it on a simple String

Answer (score 1):

If you have a normal InputStream object than You can directly get Base64 encoded stream from it using apache common library class [Base64InputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html) constructor