# BASE64DecoderStream message content to string (javax.mail)

Tags: java

javax.mail Version 1.6.2
java version : jdk1.8.0_192

I  try getting my message content (a simple Text) as string(plainText) but have a problem if my content is of type BASE64DecoderStream.
The message content should be a string similar to this :"Testnachricht 1 von 10:10 Uhr mit Umlauten ä ü ö und ß - Gleicher Text im Inhalt mit Versand und Lesebestätigung"

But on decoding I got two different behaviours with the same code:

- the expected string but without any spaces or umlauts(ä,ü,ö) similar to: "Testnachricht1von10:10UhrmitUmlautenundGleicherText"
- or an error:"BASE64Decoder: Error in encoded stream needed 4 valid base64 characters but only got 2 befor EOF, the 10 most recent characters were 'epr\195\188ft.\r\n'"

```
    private void processMessageText(Message message, MimeMessage mimeMessage){
        String plainText;
        Object content = message.getContent();
        if (content instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = (ByteArrayInputStream)content;
            byte[] data = ObjectUtil.readFully(bis);
            plainText = new String(data);
        } else if (content instanceof BASE64DecoderStream) {
            BASE64DecoderStream decodeStream = (BASE64DecoderStream) content;
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int c;
            while ((c = decodeStream.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }
            byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
            plainText = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);

        } else {
            plainText = content.toString();
        }
    }
```

Because of the old versions in use, IOUtils.toByteArray(BASE64DecoderStream) or .readAllBytes() is not possible ( [getting base64 content string of an image from a mimepart in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764504/getting-base64-content-string-of-an-image-from-a-mimepart-in-java))

the content related headers in message :

- Content-Type = application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=authenticated-enveloped-data; name=smime.p7m
- Content-Disposition = attachment; filename=smime.p7m
- Content-Transfer-Encoding = base64

the content related headers in mimeMessage:

- Content-Type = text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
- Content-Transfer-Encoding = 8bit

Comment: I nowhere see the UTF-8 encoding to be applied to get a string from the bytes - also why do you re-encode your byte array `data` after decoding it?
To give you a better solution in an answer, please provide a runnable [mre] with test data.

Comment: the bytes in decodeStream seems to be not encoded. But a decode method is called in BASE64DecoderStream.read(). Therefore the data is encoded through the decode. Thats my assumption on the behaviour i got.

Comment: You are using a `BASE64DecoderStream` that reads base64 encoded data and returns raw bytes for you. You just have to use `new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` to get your plain text from that... "encoded through the decode"? no! Please provide some of your test data also in base64 encoded form so I can give a better example in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared some small example for you.

First expected output string is obviously "Test mit Ümläuten. ööößßß". Second expected output string is "BASE64 Test mit Ümläuten. ööößßß". I encoded it externally.

I didn't use any utils for reading in the streams.

```java
package examples.stackoverflow.q73637167;

import com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.util.BASE64DecoderStream;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Q73637167 {
    private static String decodeMessage(InputStream message, Charset charset) throws IOException {
        String result = "";
        if(message instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = (ByteArrayInputStream) message;
            byte[] data = new byte[bis.available()];
            bis.read(data);
            result = new String(data, charset);
        } else if(message instanceof BASE64DecoderStream) {
            BASE64DecoderStream decodeStream = (BASE64DecoderStream) message;

            // Read all the bytes from the array in an ever growing buffer.
            // Didn't use any utils for minimum dependencies. Don't to this at home!
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int count = decodeStream.read(data);
            int startPos = 0;
            while(count == 1024) {
                byte[] addBuffer = new byte[data.length + 1024];
                System.arraycopy(data, 0, addBuffer, 0, data.length);
                startPos = data.length;
                data = addBuffer;
                count = decodeStream.read(data, startPos, 1024);
            }
            int maxlen = data.length - 1024 + count;

            // convert already decoded data in byte array to String.
            result = new String(data, 0, maxlen, charset);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // case 1: plain text
        ByteArrayInputStream byis = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                "Test mit Ümläuten. ööößßß".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        System.out.println("Plain text case: " + decodeMessage(byis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        // case 2: base64 encoded
        BASE64DecoderStream b64is = new BASE64DecoderStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                "QkFTRTY0IFRlc3QgbWl0IMOcbWzDpHV0ZW4uIMO2w7bDtsOfw5/Dnwo=".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)));
        System.out.println("Base64 case: " + decodeMessage(b64is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

If you want to process messages but not actually send them, I would recommend that you switch from java.mail-api to a different library: [Mime4J](https://james.apache.org/mime4j/index.html), a subproject of Apache James (a java mail server).

With that, message parsing is as easy as this:

```
MessageBuilder messageBuilder = new DefaultMessageBuilder();
Message message = messageBuilder.parseMessage(inputStream);
```

and you get back a nice DOM for your mime messages. (`inputStream` here is any `InputStream`, not specific for encoded or not encoded etc.)
All classes you see are part of the libs. I just found this lib recently for one of my own projects. If you use only the necessary parts, it's really small and quick. (I just needed apache-mime4j-core and apache-mime4j-dom for parsing messages from files.)

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a bit further. Sadly i'm not able to change the library, but I'll remember your suggestion for different projects :)